# usage of 'a' and 'any'

Tags: word-choice, indefinite-article

Do both these sentences mean the same?

> 1. This type of economic policy can be harmful for a nation.
> 2. This type of economic policy can be harmful for any nation.

Comment: The first talks about the nation that is harming itself by having a certain type of policy. The other is less clear - if the type of policy will harm other nations too - but it is likely meant that the policy would harm any nation implementing it

Comment: The first is the unmarked version. I'd use the second only for emphasis based on contrast: << This type of economic policy can be harmful for _any_ nation – and Elbonia's national debt is in the quadrillions. >>

Comment: @Edwin: In your context, the implied emphasis implies *- **least of all** Elbonia!*, but suppose the writer was talking about the US economy instead of Elbonia, and the preceding sentence had been *Bigger countries can protect themselves against downsides, but only to a certain extent.* Then the implied emphasis could be ***- even** the US!* Which seems kinda "opposite" to me.

Comment: @FF That's the nature of contrasts. / Elbonia never seems to mind being singled out for abuse.

Comment: @FF I've been wrongly directed here again, but on re-reading your comment, I have to disagree. I'd use 'This type of economic policy can be harmful for _any_ nation ... and as for Elbonia, ...'

Comment: In a positive context, "some" reduces to "a".  In a negative or universal context, "any" reduces to "a".  "any" and "a" mean the same unless the context excludes "any" or excludes the use of a reduced, unemphatic form.

Comment: @Edwin: Apparently, [Elbonians positively *revel* in being abused!](https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/13/132162/3349950-97722.strip.gif) Not sure if that's a kinky S&M reference or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference.

> This type of economic policy can be harmful for any nation

*Any* emphasizes that nations other than our own are included.  You can think of this sentence as having a hidden "not just your nation" or "not just our nation" attached to it.

> This type of economic policy can be harmful for a nation

This is a neutral statement that simply comments on a policy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. "A" being an indefinite article, you are not referring to a specific nation. "Any" is functioning as a pronoun (standing in for "one" country), which makes it an indefinite article in this context, again not referring to a specific nation. So while it might seem that the meanings could be different, it's really too subtle to matter.

Comment: I don't agree.  There is enough difference to matter because what may not matter to "a" or "one" nation, could very much matter to a substantial number of nations that are part of the "any nation" list.

Comment: The speaker is trying to convey that the policy is harmful on a national level. Is there any difference between saying "to a nation" or "at the national level." No? Then my previous answer stands. There is a difference between "all nations" (meaning the world) and "a nation" meaning any nation. But that's not what the OP asked.

Comment: @KristinaLopez -- Your comment could be the start of a good answer.